# Inferno - SuiteB.Encrypt generates different byte array every time

Tags: .net, encryption

I using Inferno to encrypt a string.  Encryption and decryption are working, but multiple encryptions on the same byte array seem to always yield an entirely different byte array.

The reason why this is a problem is because I need to encrypt a file path and then create that path on a local drive.  If a different byte array is generated off the same path every time, my program will keep creating new paths.  Here's the code:

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my key");

var encrypted = System.Web.HttpServerUtility
            .UrlTokenEncode(SuiteB.Encrypt(key, @"C:\some\path\to\encrypt".ToBytes().AsArraySegment()));

var decrypted = SuiteB.Decrypt(key, 
    System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(encrypted).AsArraySegment()).FromBytes();
```

On the first go, `encrypted` is set to:

```
hI_n_XrS_UuYR4heaGIfApOVco2fy0AAzU_qm8e7QMdoZg25hY2C1HFQ4w0AAvbQlv5i0DdXs3QuK50K1etHnL7ftfTS9HjLJeNCj4o6X-A-K6BVUivXBiU6DQN06ZgqVzIz3-n00
```

If I drag the debug cursor back up to it to generate it again, I get:

```
SbOst3-Qe2NqtVSNrFlHzUgQn8N-6PfKTnw4sko4BEcYuyEl7LlHB5wVRerifG9AIwo1pHYJHT57QGuIsgyvdswUjPDSuGM1dF7kUiSMZk3l1wmD3Q-KA-HQwr0yAURAMPRbKpM20
```

There is no doubt a logical and meaningful explanation as to why it's doing this, but 1) I'd like to understand why and 2) is there a way to cause it to not generate a different byte array every time?

I was initially hashing the path, but it turned out that I needed to get the original path from the hashed version.  Since you can't unhash a hash, I decided to go with encryption so that I can decrypt it later.

**Note:** Had to create new tag `inferno`.

Answer (score 1):

As to why, the encryption technique that you are employing is probably using a [block mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) other than ECB.  This is a **good thing**.  The reason this is done (and why other block modes exist) is to solve a fundamental flaw in textbook use of block ciphers.

The issue here is to do with repetitions in plaintext and the block size of your cipher.  ECB mode is the most basic cipher mode.  It literally takes one block of plaintext, encrypts it, and outputs the corresponding block of ciphertext.  That's it.  Lets say you encrypted the path `/folder1/folder2/folder1/folder2/test.txt` with AES in ECB mode.  Your ciphertext would look something like this:

```
C8A8880A02675911D5345D90387E9110
C8A8880A02675911D5345D90387E9110
86329A09EB2B6C8E686E4741CFA6C424
```

Where each line of hex is a different block of ciphertext.  You'll likely note straight away what the issue is.  The first and second blocks are the same.  This because a repetition occurs on the block boundaries of the plaintext. So this information is leaked to an attacker immediately.  This is **a lot** of information to give away about the plaintext.  Consider another scenario where the ciphertext contains either "yes" or "no" and is sent more than once.  It becomes trivial to determine which is which.  This is why ECB mode is not recommended for use.

*However*, in your use case, it might be required.  Before you start using it, ensure you understand all the ins and outs and potential flaws with ECB mode.  In the right circumstances, it actually becomes trivial to retrieve the plaintext from the ciphertext, so you'll be sacrificing a lot of the security of the encryption.

Comment: So it seems that the greatest risk with ECB mode would be that I can potentially alert the attacker that there are multiple blocks with the same data, thus reducing the effort they will need to decrypt the ciphertext.  Is that about right?  If so, one solution could be to split the path into an array at `\ `, salt/encrypt each index, then join it back again. The salt would have to somehow be static to each path and segment, yet not easy for anyone to guess.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin You shouldn't really roll your own schemes like that, it's very easy to look over things.  For example, those "salts" then become secret values that can be exposed by coincidental identical blocks.  Depending on how the encryption is being used, you might also accidentally expose the plaintext by the block byte-test method.  Your problem will likely be better solved higher up.  E.g. *why* do you think you need to encrypt the paths.  What attack are you trying to prevent?  A better method might already exist.